# How to use QSerialPort in CLion?

Tags: c++, qt

I add all required packages to CMake:

```
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(QSerialPort)
```

I can include `QIODevice` but I can't include `QSerialPort`. How to fix it?

Qt version: 5.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package is called `Qt5SerialPort` so it looks like you have a typo:

```
find_package(Qt5SerialPort)
```

The main class is called `QSerialPort` (without the 't' or the `5`). This inconsistency is a real gotcha for newcomers, unfortunately.

Comment: And also miss `5`.